# Formalizing using $\sin h \approx h$ to evaluate a limit.

Tags: analysis

Assume $f \in C^{\infty}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ satisfies $f(\sin 2t, \sin t)=0$ for all $t\in \mathbb{R}$. I want to evaluate the limit
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{h \to 0}\frac{f(2h,h)}{h}.
\end{equation*}
It seems that (from the context from which this question came up) this limit should be equal to $0$ and an intuitive rationale that supports this is to consider $h\approx \sin h$, so that if we rewrite the limit above as
\begin{equation*}
 \lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{f(2\sin\theta,\sin \theta)}{\sin\theta} \underset{\text{looks like}}{=}\hspace{0.1cm}  \lim_{\theta \to 0}\frac{f(2\sin\theta\cos \theta,\sin \theta)}{\sin\theta} = 0,  
\end{equation*}
where the last equality follows from the fact that $f$ is $0$ in points of the form $(\sin2t, \sin t)$. How to formalize this intuition?

Comment: You need an estimate for $f(2h\sqrt{1-h^2},h)-f(2h,h).$ Seems like a job for mean value theorem on the $x$ variable.

Comment: I think this did it! Thank you so so much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $h\in[-1,1]$ you get $f(2h\sqrt{1-h^2},h)=0.$

So $$\frac{f(2h,h)}{h}=\frac{f(2h,h)-f(2h\sqrt{1-h^2},h)}h\tag1$$

Now, by the mean value theorem, there is some $h'$ between $h$ and $h\sqrt{1-h^2}$ so that $$f(2h,h)-f(2h\sqrt{1-h^2},h)=2h\left(1-\sqrt{1-h^2}\right) f_x(2h',h).$$

So, if $f_x$ is bounded by $C$ in some neighborhood of $(0,0),$ then:

$$\left|\frac{f(2h,h)-f(2h\sqrt{1-h^2},h)}h\right|\leq 2C\left(1-\sqrt{1-h^2}\right)$$

So the right hand side of $(1)$ goes to zero as $h\to 0.$

So you only need that $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ exists and is bounded on some neighborhood of $(0,0).$

Answer (score 1):

$f(u,v)=au+bv+o(\|(u,v)\|)$ gives

$f(\sin(2t),\sin t)=a(2t+o(t))+b(t+o(t))+o(t)=(2a+b)t+o(t)$.

Since $f(\sin(2t),\sin t)=0$, we deduce $2a+b=0$ hence

$f(2h,h)=a(2h)+bh+o(h)=o(h)$.

Answer (score 1):

We can evaluate

$\frac{d}{dt}f(\sin (2t), \sin(t)) = (\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} 2 \cos(2t) + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cos(t))|_{(x, y) = (2t, t)} = 0$

using the multivariable chain rule. Plugging in $t = 0$ gives us $(2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})_{(x, y) = (0, 0)} = 0$.

Now note that $\lim\limits_{h \to 0} \frac{f(2h, h)}{h} = \frac{d}{dt} f(2t, t)|_{t = (0, 0)}$ by the definition of the derivative. We apply the multivariable chain rule again to get that this derivative is $(2 \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y})_{(x, y) =(0, 0)}$. But we’ve already demonstrated that this quantity is $0$.

Answer (score 0):

You would want to be careful with intuition such as this.  For example, suppose you defined a function $f$ by
$$f(x,y) = \frac{x - 2y\sqrt{1-y^2}} {y^3}.$$
Then $f(\sin(2\theta), \sin(\theta)) = 0$ at least for $-\frac{\pi}{2} \le \theta \le \frac{\pi}{2}$.  However, $f(2h, h) = \frac{2h - 2h\sqrt{1-h^2}}{h^3}$, and a Taylor expansion of the square root term will show that $f(2h, h) \to 1$ as $h\to 0$, so $\frac{f(2h, h)}{h}$ would have no limit.

Of course, this has the issue that $f(x,y)$ is not defined on the $x$-axis.  You could try making some adjustments near $y=0$ to get a better defined function.  However, if you do that, you might see that you continue to get functions which are not differentiable at the origin -- as the following argument using the differentiability will show:

Under the given conditions, in particular, $f$ is continuous at $(0, 0)$.  Therefore, $(\sin(2t), \sin(t)) \to (0, 0)$ as $t\to 0$ implies $f(0, 0) = \lim_{t\to 0} f(\sin(2t), \sin(t)) = 0$.  Also, using the multivariate chain rule, we have that
$$\left. \frac{d}{dt} [f(\sin(2t), \sin(t))] \right|_{t=0} = 2 f_x(0, 0) + f_y(0, 0) = 0.$$
Now since $f(0, 0) = 0$, the given limit is equal by definition to
$$\left. \frac{d}{dt} [f(2t, t)] \right|_{t=0} = 2 f_x(0, 0) + f_y(0, 0) = 0.$$

Comment: Your example $f$ is not in $C^{\infty}(\mathbb R^2),$ is it?

Comment: Thanks for the comment on caution! However as I described in the post, there is a greater context that suggested that the limit had to be 0. In any case, By looking at the last part of your post, I have to ask, how can you tell that $2f_x(0,0)+f_y(0,0)=0$? I also thought about it this way but I didnt know how to conclude from there.

Comment: Right, it's not.  My point with that example is: unless you make tighter error estimates, just figuring $(\sin(2t), \sin t)$ is "close enough" to $(2t, t)$ isn't necessarily going to give you a valid conclusion.  But, it does turn out that the differentiability at $(0, 0)$ is sufficient to get such a tighter error estimate (and the answer by Anne Bauval makes it a bit more explicit what the estimate of $f$ is near $(0, 0)$ based on that assumption, and why it's sufficient.